# Клавиатура Xcode iPhone Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

У меня в эмуляторе не закрывается клавиатура при вводе в текстовые поля(Text Field), подскажите, как объявить и прокодить кнопку Return(Done),для того чтобы по нажатию на нее, клавиатура исчезала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @zhenyab, добавьте пояснение, что еще нужно, чтобы этот метод был объявлен в классе, который должен быть сделан делегатом `UITextField`.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich Вы имеете ввиду добавить в header класса <UITextFieldDelegate>?

Comment: Я думаю @Blackintenum работает с xib или со storyboard, поэтому ему нужно сконнектить delegate текстового поля (который в xib или storyboard...) с соответствующим .h файлом view-контроллера и да))) - нужно добавить <UITextFieldDelegate> в этот же .h-файл контроллера, чтобы сделать этот контроллер делегатом UITextField.

Comment: В целом Вы правы, но если он программно добавляет UITextField? То дегелегатом нужно назначить собственно класс (self) программно. Сейчас вроде все учтено :)

Спасибо за дополнения!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, да я сам коннектить умею)

Answer (score 0):

Добавляю к существующему правильному ответу: гляньте туториал Apple [Your First App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH7-SW2) начиная с заголовка `Create Outlets for the Text Field and the Label`. Если с английским проблема - не страшно, так как там картинки очень хорошо всё показывают. Вообще то, что вы пытаетесь делать сегодня, вчера и позавчера очень напоминает всё то, чему посвящен весь туториал, советую посмотреть его целиком.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

if (nextResponder) {

    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

} else {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

return NO;
}
```